# How to enable meta-transactions for Polygon contract

Tags: solidity, polygon, meta-transactions

I am going to enable meta-transactions for my contract (simple ERC1155 contract, truffle project) on Polygon network to be used by OpenSea, checked the following tutorials and contracts and understood that native meta-transactions could be the best choice:

https://docs.opensea.io/docs/polygon-basic-integration
https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/meta-transactions/blob/main/contracts/ERC1155MetaTransactionMaticSample.sol

And have the following questions:

- Is there any tested/audited npm module which provides implementation of `NativeMetaTransaction` and `ContextMixin` contracts ? I could find this module, but not sure if this is the best choice: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@maticnetwork/pos-portal,
- As far as I can see `EIP712Base` contract (the parent contract of `NativeMetaTransaction` ) extends `Initializable`, which assumes my contract to be upgradable, whereas I am not planning to make my contract upgradable. Also the solidity conpiler version used in the module is `0.6.x`, whereas it is `0.8.x` in my contract,
- Is there any detailed tutorial, documentation or best practices about enabling native meta-transactions on Polygon contract, also how does the OpenSea call meta-transaction functions ?

Would be happy to get any suggestion/advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you found out how to do it?

Comment: Yes, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: I have followed the instructions here:
https://docs.opensea.io/docs/polygon-basic-integration#meta-transactions

and here:

https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/meta-transactions/blob/main/contracts/ERC1155MetaTransactionMaticSample.sol

I have extended my contract from `ContextMixin` and `NativeMetaTransaction` contracts defined in the github repo.

Comment: and do you use GSN to interact with it?